# sqlite ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK and consecutive queries

Tags: sqlite, transactions

I use an sqlite `ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK` clause for keeping a table of ressources that may be occupied. This is done with repeated statements, that run quite eficcent within an transaction. Like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES(17);
INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES(18);
INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES(19);
COMMIT;
```

The places are constrained by an `... place UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK ...` clause.

However, it seems transactions are not sane for this use. In fact, if one `UNIQE` conflict triggers, the transacion is rolled back, even if we don't hit the `COMMIT` statement. The following statements preceding `COMMIT` and `COMMIT` itself are executed it seems, now as single statements with implicit commit. Isn't this behaviour kind of useless? I would expect nothing to happen until `COMMIT` is invoked, and the `ROLLBACK` resulting in the state before `BEGIN` if triggered.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a conflict resolution clause always is the current statement, not any following statements.
This works as [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).

It is common for programs, when they encounter an error, to fix whatever caused the error and to retry the statement, or to execute another statement.
Therefore, the database assumes that any command that you execute is a command that you actually want to execute.

The ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK clause does not make sense for your application.
You should use the normal ON CONFLICT ABORT algorithm, and either handle conflicts by not executing any following commands:

```py
try:
    db.execute("BEGIN")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO places(place) VALUES(17)")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO places(place) VALUES(18)")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO places(place) VALUES(19)")
    db.execute("COMMIT")
except:
    db.execute("ROLLBACK")
```

or insert all values in a single statement so that any ABORT automatically rolls back the other values:

```sql
INSERT INTO places(place) VALUES (17), (18), (19)
```

Comment: Ok, but using one statement is obviously less capable then using several ones, as for example you can not mix INSERT and UPDATE or modify more then one table at once. And checking for errors after every query does brake asynchroneous operation, where my application send a bunch of queries against the sqlite3 binary.

Comment: Also it is quite funny that when the possible conflicting query is issued as the last one, it may in fact `ROLLBACK` any queries issued before on conflict, while placing it in the middle of a transaction would not give this feature...

Comment: So one actually can combine different statements, as long the possible conflicting one is only one and issued last.

Comment: I think what I ask for is an `ON CONFLICT` rule that does `ROLLBACK` to occur at the natural transactions end, usually the `COMMIT;` statement.

Comment: Yes, but the intended behavour is not done by sqlite but by the exception handling of your code. So it is not portable to my asynchroneous use case, in which a web server triggers the queries without waiting on any single one to complete.

Comment: SQLite is an *embedded* database; asynchronous operation does not make sense in the first place.

Comment: The `sqlite3` binary is an runnable process, asynchroneous operation make perfect sense for any process.

Comment: I do not asked to hack on sqlite, I merely asked in hope to find a nifty solution to this problem.

Comment: The `sqlite3` command-line shell does not offer any programming logic; you have to write your own code.

Comment: Contrary to the opening statement in the answer, an "ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK" will cause an *explicit* transaction to roll back, even if the transaction contains multiple, preceding statements.  The entire transaction is rolled back if the particular constraint fails.  The scope is not necessarily limited to the current statement.  That is only true of implicit transactions created for individual statements executed outside of an explicit transaction (or savepoint).  My answer explains further.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that as of *SQLite version 3.27.2* using the *.Net binding System.Data.SQLite 1.0.110.0*, the ON CONFLICT clause mentioned in the question works as the OP desires and as [documentation explains](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).

Neither the specific version (other than the sqlite3 tag), nor sufficient DDL code, nor any details about the coding environment was given in the question to know for sure why the statement did not work as expected.  Thus, this answer is meant as an *updated reference to the primary question* rather than a solution to the OP's particular situation.

I did however experience similar behavior as described in the question prior to testing the `... UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK` clause directly in C# code using the latest versions given above.  I had first attempted to test the code with 3rd-party tools *SQLiteStudio v3.2.1 (using SQLite 3.24.0)* and *DB Browser for SQLite 3.11.2 (using SQLite 3.27.2)*.  After many frustrating tests, I now assume that both of those tools implement their own statement/transaction handling and/or compilation options that seem to completely mess up the underlying transaction behavior of SQLite.  For both of those tools, it seemed as though the `ON CONFLICT` clauses of the `CREATE TABLE` statement causes buggy, incorrect transaction behavior.  For instance, DB Broswer was allowing individual statements within a supposed transaction to be committed!, even when the transaction was seemingly rolled back and an error was returned.  In that regard, I experienced problems just as described in the question, but it turns out that the problem is not with SQLite directly, rather the 3rd-party tools.

It wasn't until my direct tests in C# code (without any other activity on the connection) was I able to confirm that SQLite3 properly handles the ON CONFLICT declarations on the table columns.  This is also a caution about 3rd party tools attempt to automate management of SQLite databases.  All of the extra calls to the database for providing the management features can interfere with otherwise valid SQL statements and transactions.

---

I first setup a table using the following SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE places (
    id     INTEGER    PRIMARY KEY
                      AUTOINCREMENT
                      NOT NULL
                      UNIQUE,
    place  INTEGER    NOT NULL
                      UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK);

INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES (18);
INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES (5);
```

Next I executed additional inserts inside an explicit transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES (17);
INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES (18); --Should fail due to non-unique value
INSERT INTO places (place) VALUES (19);
COMMIT;
```

Upon executing each prepared statement separately (within separate `SQLite.SQLiteCommand` objects), the indicated statement failed, causing a ROLLBACK of the transaction.  I verified the rollback by checking the status of the connection querying the `SQLiteConnection.AutoCommit` property (which returns false if within an explicit transaction), but also by attempting an explicit `ROLLBACK` which failed with an error stating that no transaction was active.  To further verify that no other statements had been unexpectedly committed, I queried the database from another process and found that no additional rows had been inserted and committed.