# SQLite Transactions not working

Tags: sql, sqlite, transactions

I'm trying to perform an SQLite transaction in DB Browser for SQLite, but there's an unexpected behavior. I misspelled the name of a table intentionally in one of my query, but still its inserting data in other tables except for the one I misspelled.
Here is my query:

```
BEGIN; 
INSERT INTO vouchers (person_id, date, amount, description, mop, transaction_id) VALUES('XXXX','XXXX','XXX','XXX','XXXX','XXXX'); 
INSERT INTO personal_info (id, name, address, city, state, mobile, member) VALUES('XXXX','XXXX','XXXX','XXX','XXX','XX','XX'); 
INSERT INTO membership_info (person_id, join_date, transaction_id) VALUES('XXX','XXX','XXX'); 
INSERT INTO cas (id, person_id, date, remarks, type, amount, balance) VALUES('XXXX','XXXX','XXXXX','XXXX','XXX','XXX','XXX') ; 
COMMIT;
```

I intentionally misspelled the the table name in last query `INSERT INTO cas` instead of `INSERT INTO cash` but still rest of the queries are working except the last one. I also tried replacing the `COMMIT;` with `ROLLBACK;`

Comment: Yes - that's how the SQL works. What did you expect?

Comment: Have a look here, which would seem to be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108253/sqlite-on-conflict-rollback-and-consecutive-queries

Comment: But it's a transaction, if a query fails rest of the queries should not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it's a transaction, if a query fails rest of the queries should not work

Nope, that's not how transactions work.

When you commit a transaction, all changes after you started your transaction become visible to others in the database. In case of rollback, the changes are discarded.

An invalid SQL does not produce any changes inside the transaction but just returns an error. It's *your* responsibility as a programmer to detect errors and to choose the appropriate resolution strategy to you, such as rolling back the transaction, or committing nevertheless.